# Can't Focus on dojo Button OK

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I'm trying to run a `dojo` (searchNotFound) if another dojo of searching (searchDlg) not finding result

So, the dojo (searchNotFound) is up , but not focusing on `OK` (cause I've an event `onkeypress` on this Button OK)

So, this is my code :

**Function FindString() :**

```
      function findString(str) {

        //Some Code

        //if serach not founding , running dojo searchNotFound
        if (!strFound) {
                    dojo.widget.byId("searchDlg").hide();
                    dojo.widget.byId("searchNotFound").show();
                    dojo.byId("searchnotfound_close").focus(); --> ****** not working ******
                }

}
```

**OnKeyPress event on OK Button (searchnotfound_close) of dojo (searchNotFound) :**

--> Works Fine

```
<button class="btn dlg" id="searchnotfound_close" onkeypress="javascript:closeSearchNotFound(event)"><span key="ok">Ok</span></button>
```

**Function closeSearchNotFound(event)**

--> Works Fine

```
//#96985
function closeSearchNotFound(event) {
if(event.which == 13){
    dojo.widget.byId('searchNotFound').hide();
    dojo.widget.byId('searchDlg').show();
    }
}
//
```

See This test video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cM4rCtP7REA&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Does the dojo.byId("searchnotfound_close") return the dom? If it does, then try to set focus in setTimeout(function () { dojo.byId("searchnotfound_close").focus(); }, 1000).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming 'searchNotFound' is a dijit/Dialog. show() is asynchronous because it shows the dialog with an animation. Because of that, show() returns a [dojo/promise/Promise](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/promise/Promise.html). Once the promise completes, the dialog is fully rendered and your subsequent search should work.

Use the promise and register your own callback:

```js
registry.byId("searchNotFound").show().then(
  function() {
    dojo.byId("searchnotfound_close").focus();
  });
```